# Facing issue while installing active admin with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have included `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'` in my gem file and run bundle install.

When I run

```
rails g active_admin:install AdminUser
```

it gives me error

> invoke  devise /home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@module/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0.pre1/lib/generators/active_admin/devise/devise_generator.rb:21:in
>   `rescue in install_devise': To use devise you need to specify it in
>   your Gemfile. If you don't want to use devise, run the generator with
>   --skip-users. (ActiveAdmin::GeneratorError)

Please guide me how to solve this.

Answer (score 6):

Add in your Gemfile the following line:

```
gem 'devise'
```

then

```
bundle install
```

Now you are ready to continue.

**Note** I would not recommend to go with the second option (skipping users).

Comment: `bundle update` will get the latest versions of all the gems in the Gemfile, as opposed to `bundle install`, which will simply install all the gems specified in the Gemfile locally, and is the right thing to do in this case. `bundle update` can cause compatibility issues with existing gems if not used carefully, as upgrading to the latest version of each gem is not always desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Add `devise` to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'devise'
```

Then run:

`bundle install`